# Cannot see my drupal page, when set with online server

Tags: drupal

I have installed kloxo control panel, this is the address http://173.212.227.142:7778/. Then I made domain for my test site, which shows me preview from this link, http://173.212.227.142:7778/sitepreview/kids.com/index.html, which is right.

Now I have installed drupal but it is very hard for me to set here. I have made changes in configuration file like database, and in base_url. But didnot getting the site and it shows me a blank page.Site should come with this address, http://173.212.227.142:7778/sitepreview/kids.com/kids/index.php. I made the base_url as http://173.212.227.142:7778/sitepreview/kids.com/kids.

Please suggest me the solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a problem in your settings.php file, Drupal won't be able to connect to the database but will show you a page telling you such. The White Screen of Death means there is some kind of php error. It is difficult to know what kind of error from your description. Look in your error logs for php errors and tell us what you see, and it will be easier to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

The white page *could* be the result of a php error, possibly due to a configuration/setting oversight. You should check your Webservers error log(s) for this, as they might give you some hints on possible causes.

Answer (score 0):

Read this: http://drupal.org/node/158043